# d2rq generate-mapping command for Oracle database

Tags: oracle, ojdbc, d2rq

I'm trying to call the d2rq generate-mapping command for Oracle databases from command line.

My command string is:

```
C:\d2rq-0.8.1> generate-mapping -o output.ttl -u user -p pass -d oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

I have tried a lot of suggested answers such as:

```
C:\d2rq-0.8.1> generate-mapping -o output.ttl -u user -p pass -d oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl
```

and I keep getting

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

I read that this exception could be happening because there's something wrong in my command string.

The ojdbc I have is from this page

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Is it not the correct driver?? or is there something wrong in my command?

Appreciate any help, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the software it is bit outdated because In my case I had to use the Connector/J 5.1.49 (from  here  https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Try a previous version in Oracle.

Comment: How exactly does one do that?

Comment: In my scenario, I've dowloaded the .jar file and I moved to the lib folder